# Cheapest iButton (1-wire) adaptor/programmer scheme

Tags: connector, programmer, 1-wire

I want to be able to read and write and program [iButton](http://www.maximintegrated.com/products/ibutton/) (1-wire) devices mainly [DS1990A](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/2829) and EPROMs. The problem is that any [driver chips](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/ver/F/id/2995) and [readers and adapters](http://para.maximintegrated.com/en/search.mvp?fam=ibuttonr_a&tree=master) by maxim are expensive here.

Is there any other cheaper DIY solution to connect iButton to computer using any usual interfaces (usb, serial, parallel, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Most microcontrollers will do. The 1-wire protocol is not difficult to implement, there are many examples available. A UART will give you serial connection (you'll need a driver like MAX232 to connect to a real serial port). Many microcontrollers have USB device controllers these days, too. Writing firmware that implements a bridge shouldn't be a difficult task (with a possible exception of some existing software that communicates with a reader using an unknown protocol). You can choose one of many commercially available development boards if you don't want to design your own, too.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an FTDI USB-to-logic-level-serial convertor (available as a pre-fabricated cable from Digi-Key for about $20 in the USA; not sure about availability elsewhere).  Tie ground to IButton ground and Rx to the IButton data; tie the Tx pin to Rx via 1K resistor.  One can send a reset pulse by selecting a low baud rate and sending a zero byte.  Otherwise, one can send zeroes and ones by selecting a baud rate of 115,200 or so, and sending FF to generate a short pulse or F0 to generate a long one.  One should expect to receive an FF, FE, or FC for a short pulse, and probably an FC, F8, F0, or E0 for a long one.

Answer (score 2):

The options above might be a little more inexpensive, but if you value your time you'll quickly see you'll have to spend it implementing 1-wire, which requires careful timing to ensure proper operation.

If you want an inexpensive and quick solution that just works, [The Bus Pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate) is a great tool. The bonus is that it supports so much more than 1-Wire, so it can do basically anything you need (and if you work on it you can further expand it). Can't go wrong for $30 that does all you want and more.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of driver depends on the distance of your 1-wire bus. If its within a PCB, or a few tens of centimetres, you can bit-bang the protocol from your micro controller. If you need a longer twisted pair link, with multiple devices on lines up to 300 metres, the Maxim driver chips are worth buying. When configured for long-line mode they use controlled rise times and adjustable driving currents to reduce ringing. They are a UART controlled protocol state machine and analogue driver on one tiny part.

I used a DS2480 to drive a 100m CAT5 bus of DS1822+PAR temperature sensors and it's reliable in the field.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Maxim DS1413](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/maxim/DS1413.pdf), [Maxim DS9097](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS9097U-DS9097U-S09.pdf) and [DS9490](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS9490-DS9490R.pdf). Or in as so much as the internal schematic presented in the datasheets. The first is done with **just diodes**. The second and the third require a maxim driver chip, which you said is expensive.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58958/1-Wire-USB-Interface) is a transistor + usb-uart cable version.

The other option is make your own. Any arduino/avr, pic, msp430 can do it. Most have libraries available. [Here](http://www.edaboard.com/thread236905.html) is a v-usb/atmega8 project (actual project in polish) [Here](http://www.poempelfox.de/ds1820tousb/) is a attiny v-usb version.

You can do it pennies on the dollar, if you put in some coding work.

Answer (score 1):

Simple COM port interface with Delphi source:
http://www.rtcs.ru/article_detail.asp?id=73